# Searching for substring with special character using regex

Tags: c#, regex, text

I had a very quick question as a regex newbie.  I am wanting to do a simple substring search within a given string using regex. So far I have:

```
string text = "One (1) cat";
Regex regexsearch = new Regex("\b(" + Regex.Escape(text) + ")\b")
string fulltext = "One (1) cat sat on the wall";
if(regexsearch.IsMatch(fulltext)
{
     \\Do thing
}
```

However, I am skipping over my function each time, even though there should be a match.

I think there is something I am not quite understanding about Regex.Escape.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: \b is word boundary, did you meant ^ and $ (start and end of string anchors)?

Comment: Hi @Gusman...I was using word boundary because there are cases where my substring will exist in the middle of the full text (i.e. There was One (1) cat who sat on the wall).  Does that seem incorrect?

Comment: If the match can be between other words it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Regex.Escape(...)` doesn't do what you think it does it seems.
If you dump out the contents of your `Regex.Escape(text)` then you'll get the following (without the quotes):

```
"One\ \(1\)\ cat"
```

Which I'm sure isn't what you want.

```
var text = "One (1) cat";
text = text.Replace("(", Regex.Escape("(")).Replace(")", Regex.Escape(")"));
var regexsearch = new Regex(text);
var  fulltext = "One (1) cat sat on the wall";
if (regexsearch.IsMatch(fulltext)) {
    Console.WriteLine("okay");
}
```

The problem is you are escaping too much. Note the parenthesis above where I put slashes in front of each. If you were to do a Regex.Escape(...) instead on just the (1) it would probably be fine.

Comment: Thanks @KSib.  I am looking to iterate over several values for my text variable (i.e. Two (2) cats, Three (3) cats etc.).  Do you know, is there a good way to programatically escape the parentheses so I don't have to write a regex for each phrase?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ")" character in your code.

```
if(regexsearch.IsMatch(fulltext))
{
     \\ Do thing
}
```